# How do i clean inside of my iMac?

Tags: imac, macos

I want to clean the inside of my iMac. The mac : iMac Mid-2007

How do i clean the dust from inside or clean inside of it. Basically im saying how do I open the mac?

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: My mac is running slow and theres always dust around the mac. So im taking a step forward.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's an access door on the bottom of the Mac which can be unscrewed.

[image: Screw highlighted on bottom of iMac]

For further access, you need to take the glass off, which is fixed with fourteen magnets.

[image: Image of glass being removed from front of iMac using two suction cups]

<sup>Source: http://www.ifixit.com/Guide/iMac+Intel+20-Inch+EMC+2133+and+2210+Hard+Drive+Replacement/1008</sup>

Answer (score 1):

The internals of your iMac are accessed [through the looking glass](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1758).

You'll want to get some suction cups and special tools if you care to. There are somewhat nice take apart guides at ifixit.com and also pause before you go in to realize that parts can be very expensive and if you rip the display cable off the logic board, you can do multiple hundreds of dollars of damage in an instant should the LCD panel slip if the iMac pivots when you don't expect it.